# Image Upload Custom Form Field for Category and Custom Taxonomy

Tags: categories, images, taxonomy, media-library

I am currently customizing a Wordpress Theme, and I want to add a new form field on Category for uploading an image. The image should be retrieved from the Media Library.

I found out that there are ways to do this, but I am not sure which one is the best practice or the recommended approach.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you could use [Advanced Custom Fields](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). If you can't have a dependency on ACF in your theme, you could have a look at this [older article](https://en.bainternet.info/wordpress-taxonomies-extra-fields-the-easy-way/)

Comment: You can user either ACF or toolset for this requirement.By using both of this we will get the uploaded images in the media libraray

Comment: @Michael thank you for your suggestion. I do not want to use Plugin to do that. I will attentively look at the suggested article.

Comment: @Adarsh thank you for your response. I understand that ACF is a nice plugin, but I prefer not to use plugin. I wonder what is the toolset you are refering to?

Comment: @MardySamAn its also a plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several tasks you need to perform when you choose to do with custom code. And I personally think they're complicated tasks. Here is the list of what I can imagine.

1. Hook to the category edit page to add a new form for upload image. This can be done with the hook `{$taxonomy}_add_form_fields`.
2. Handle the image upload. Depend on what you want the upload field to be, it can be a HTML `file` input or a button to open the Media Library popup.
3. If it's just a `file` input, then you have to work with pure PHP to handle upload via `$_FILES`.
4. If it uses Media Library, then you need to work with JS to trigger the popup.

As you're developing a theme, it can take a lot of time working on that. Besides, it belongs to plugin territory.

So, I'd suggest using a plugin for that. [Meta Box](https://metabox.io) framework with [MB Term Meta](https://metabox.io/plugins/mb-term-meta/) extension works great in this case.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Meta Box.

Comment: I appreciate your precise answer. I will consider using the suggested plugin.